# How to make a 'super admin' in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

A super admin is an user with special uid which is able to access of everyone to edit their profile and publish new content.

How to make a super admin?

Comment: Can you provide your current db structure and the security rules, please.

Comment: @Orlandster I have no db stucture and the security rules, you may create your own schema such as users, moderators, and admin. Just a basic idea.

Comment: There is no super admin concept in Firebase. Every user is like every other user. However, you can give different users access to your Firebase based on rules you implement. For example, supposed you had a users node where each child had a key of uid and then the children of each uid node contained more information about that user. You could have a /uid/user_type = "Super" node. With rules, you can deny access to all users that do not have a user_type of "Super" which would allow only a Super user to access that node. I would suggest working with Firebase a bit to more fully understand rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it's all about data structure and the belonging security rules.
To get started, build a data structure where you have some kind of `user roles` in it.

For example like this:

```
{
    "data" : {
       "user1id" : {
            "name" : "MisterX"
        },
        "user2id" : {
            "name" : "John Doe"
        }
    },
    "users" : {
        "user1id" : {
            "role" : "admin"
        },
        "user2id" : {
            "role" : "member"
        }
    }
}
```

Each user has a property called `role`.

Now you can define your security rules and make use of the `role` property to define the right access rights:

```
"data" : {
    "$userid" : {
        ".read" : true,
        ".write" : "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role') === 'admin'",    
      }
  }
```

In the case above just admins are able to write to the `data/userid` node. You can apply this to all the different nodes you want to.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using custom user attributes. It is more efficient and cheaper than using Real Time Database to lookup if a user is an Admin on every authenticated request:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

You would set the Admin role on the user upon creation:
`admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {admin: true})`

You can propagate it to the client after ID token refresh.

`currentUser.getIdToken(true)`

Then you can simply enforce the rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "adminContent": {
      ".read": "auth.token.admin === true",
      ".write": "auth.token.admin === true",
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't use rules or Firebase RTDB, then enforce it on your backend by parsing it from the ID token via Firebase Admin SDK:

```
 // Verify the ID token first.
 admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then((claims) => {
   if (claims.admin === true) {
     // Allow access to requested admin resource.
   }
 });
```

Comment: It requires Firebase SDK, isn't kind of backend to edit users without going to firebase console?